# How do I "project" the local rotation of an objects rotation around a camera at the center of 3d space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, projection

I've been working on a bit of a dumb project. I have created a software renderer using Unity's Texture2D.SetPixel. The renderer is all set up and working, and I've started working on getting the camera flying around the objects. I've projected the global space of the objects to look as if its in local space, making it seem as if the camera is flying around the objects instead of visa versa. but now the problem is getting the objects to looks as if they are rotated properly.

The first thing I tried was subtracting the camera rotation from the object rotation but that didn't work, so I tried adding it which did work but only if I looked ad the objects from a front facing angle. If I went behind the objects it started to break. I have a demo scene with some arrows that point up on their local rotation(that being 0,0,0). if I do nothing to the rotation to make it seem like the cameras rotating, the arrows just point up relative to the screen as they are just being moved around.

[Example with no fix attempt (youtube)](https://youtu.be/i6pdjHCIMCc)

here's a video with an example of the the first things I tried, that being subtracting, then adding, the camera rotation form the cube rotation.

[Fix attempts one and two (youtube)](https://youtu.be/1aFHcD7k_F4)

I should state that they rotate based on x, y, z. z being forward, y being up.

I will also link the function that draws the objects.

```
 public void Draw(RenderContext context,RCamera _Cam, Matrix4f ViewProjection,Matrix4f proj, Vector3 pos, Vector3 rot, Texture2D texture)
        {
            /* Vector3 nPos = pos - _Cam.Pos;
             Vector3 rotatedPos = new Vector3();*/


           

            // -( (Mathf.Sin(_Cam.Rot.x)) * (Mathf.Cos(_Cam.Rot.y)) )


            float x = _Cam.Rot.x;
            
            float y = _Cam.Rot.y;
            
            float z = _Cam.Rot.z;


            //the problem child line
            Vector3 nRot = rot+ new Vector3(x,y,z);




            //Mathf.Sin(_Cam.Rot.x) * Mathf.Cos(_Cam.Rot.y)
            Vector3 camRot = new Vector3(x, y, z );


            //  Vector3 nRot = rot - camRot*_Cam.Fov*Mathf.Deg2Rad;

            //Vector3 nRot = new Vector3( Mathf.Sin( rot.x)+ Mathf.Cos( y),Mathf.Sin( rot.y)+Mathf.Cos( y), Mathf.Sin( rot.z)+ Mathf.Cos( z));



            Debug.Log(rot.x * (x * _Cam.Fov * Mathf.Deg2Rad));


           







            RotateMatrixX(_Cam,pos.x - _Cam.Pos.x, pos.z - _Cam.Pos.z, 0 - _Cam.Rot.y);
           
            RotateMatrixY(_Cam,pos.y - _Cam.Pos.y, _Cam.RotatedZ, 0 - _Cam.Rot.x);

            Vector3 rotPos = new Vector3(_Cam.RotatedX , _Cam.RotatedY, _Cam.RotatedZ);


            Matrix4f translation = new Matrix4f().InitTranslation(rotPos.x, rotPos.y, rotPos.z);
            Matrix4f rotation = new Matrix4f().InitRotation(nRot.x, nRot.y, nRot.z);
            Matrix4f scale = new Matrix4f().InitScale(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);
            Matrix4f transform = proj.Mul(translation.Mul(rotation));


            if (rotPos.z>0)
            {
                DrawMesh(context, ViewProjection, transform, texture);

            }
         
        }
```

I've left some of my attempts as comments I figured they'd be useful later but they all just end with a different flavor of wonkiness.

I've been at this for a couple days, maybe you'll catch something I missed, if so thank you in advance.
have a pleasant existence.

Comment: Euler angles or quaternions can be convenient for setting or modifying an objects rotations. But when it comes down to rendering you should convert everything to matrices and multiply them together. [This post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29260/transform-matrix-multiplication-order) seem to have a decent overview of the common matrices and their order.

Comment: I still don't fully get what exactly you are trying to achieve and why but in general for the rotations I would rather stick to `Quaternion` and use `Quaternion.Inverse` in order to calculate the local rotation (`var localRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(cameraRotation) * worldRotation;` will result in the `worldRotation` converted to a rotation relative to the camera's world rotation)

Comment: Also what is `Matrix4f` and why not use the built-in `Matrix4x4` and things like [`Matrix4x4.TRS`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.TRS.html), [`Matrix4x4.invserse`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4-inverse.html), etc

Comment: @derHugo thank you for the advice, ill give the quaternion solution a shot, but the reason I'm having to do all this extra work around stuff is because I'm (for the most part) 
 following an 8 year old tutorials on software rendering don in java, and having to translate it to C#, and I'm using a custom class to mimic the version matrix4x4 he ahs in his video since i don't completely understand matrix multiplication yet. I'm still learning.
    this is the tutorial I've used as reference (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_vvC2G7vRo&list=PLEETnX-uPtBUbVOok816vTl1K9vV1GgH5).

Comment: on top of that his method of getting transforms and quaternions to work directly in the projected matrices just leads to weird stretching,and I'm just working around that by ignoring his method of doing transforms.

Comment: @derHugo I've tried he quaternions method of getting this to work but since the local rotation of the models is zero i just end up with the same result as if I didn't try to fix the rotations since its just multiplying by zero.

Comment: @Indie but in that case `Quaternion.Inverse(cameraRotation) * Quaternion.identity` is still something different to `Quaternion.identity` or `cameraRotation` ...

Comment: Still my question would be **why**? What do you need his for? Unity already provides you with an entire rendering pipeline and game engine ... in the end this is anyway used to produce your final output result isn't it? So m a bit confused why you would do this "manually" on the CPU side anyway .. or in other words - Why use Unity and go through `c#`? Why not stick to Java and use the same stuff the tutorial does? After compiling you could even use it as a plugin in `c#` again

Comment: @derHugo ah, this is just a fun side project. I realize I could do all the stuff directly form the tutorial but 1, I do eventually wan tot move onto my own game engine or game tool kit and understanding software rendering is a good start  into learning rendering on the gpu, and 2 it just fun to say I made a renderer out of a texture in unity, plus I have a runtime compiler I've made so I can basically make a fantasy console like pico 8 with it. its just  fun.

Comment: @Indie I see fair enough! Was just asking to understand the indents a bit better ;)  I think as said you might even go directly through `Matrix4x4.inverse` similar to the quaternion formula above which should give you the relative translation, rotation and scale in a single go

Comment: @derHugo I'll see what I can do, but all the projection is handled i just want to move the world around the camera to seem as if the camera is moving around the world